# NativeScript Documents directory seen in iOS Files application

Tags: ios, nativescript

According to NativeScript documentation here: https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/file-system#knownfolders-methods

The documents folder is private for the application and not accessible from Users/External apps.

However I did see it in the Files application on iOS 16.3.1 I did not see it on iPhone simulator simulating iOS 16.1
Is it something with iOS 16.3.1?

How can I have a folder that is private to the app not not seen from other applications?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

It seems that Apple added a parameter in info.plist
If you set UISupportsDocumentBrowser to false than Documents folder will not be seen in "on my iPhone".

For some reason this parameter was set to true in my application.